# BLDC motor simulation

Tags: simulation, inverter, brushless-dc-motor, back-emf, state-space

I would like to simulate BLDC motor in programming language other than Matlab or Simulink, but have problem with several equations and inverter output. BLDC motor scheme is following:
[image]
After searching state-space model of BLDC motor so I could do simulation with equations:
\begin{equation}
Y = CX\\
\dot X = AX + BU
\end{equation}

I found out that in many papers (specificaly in http://webfiles.portal.chalmers.se/et/MSc/BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf, page 24 of pdf file) the state-space model of BLDC motor is following:

\begin{equation}
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
i_a\\
i_b\\
ω_m\\
θ_m
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -\frac{R}{L} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{k_f}{J} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=:
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3L} & \frac{1}{3L} & 0\\
-\frac{1}{3L} & \frac{1}{3L} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{J}\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{ab} - e_{ab}\\
v_{bc} - e_{bc}\\
T_e - T_L
\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Y=
\begin{bmatrix}
i_a\\
i_b\\
i_c\\
ω_m\\
θ_m
\end{bmatrix}\tag{6}
\end{equation}

where:
\$R\$, \$L\$ - resistance, inductance per phase,
\$v_{ab}\$, \$v_{bc}\$ - phase-to-phase voltages,
\$e_{ab}\$, \$e_{bc}\$ - phase-to-phase back-emf's,
\$i_a\$, \$i_b\$, \$i_c\$ - phase currents,
\$T_e\$, \$T_l\$ - electrical torque, load torque,
\$J\$ - rotor inertia,
\$k_f\$ - friction coefficient,
\$ω_m\$ - rotor speed,
\$θ_m\$ - mechanical torque

Back-emf's per phase (\$e_a\$, \$e_b\$, \$e_c\$) and electrical torque can be derived as:

\begin{equation}
θ_e = \frac{p}{2}θ_m\tag{7}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
F(θ_e) = \begin{cases}
1, & 0 \le θ_e<\frac{2\pi}{3}\\
1-\frac{6}{\pi}(θ_e-\frac{2\pi}{3}), & \frac{2\pi}{3} \le θ_e<\pi\\
-1, & \pi \le θ_e <\frac{5\pi}{3}\\
-1+\frac{6}{\pi}(θ_e-\frac{5\pi}{3}), & \frac{5\pi}{3} \le θ_e<2\pi\\
\end{cases}\tag{8}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}
e_a = \frac{k_e}{2}ω_mF(θ_e)\tag{9}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_b = \frac{k_e}{2}ω_mF(θ_e-\frac{2π}{3})\tag{10}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_c = \frac{k_e}{2}ω_mF(θ_e-\frac{4π}{3})\tag{11}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
T_e = \frac{k_t}{2}[F(θ_e)i_a + F(θ_e-\frac{2π}{3})i_b + F(θ_e-\frac{4π}{3})i_c]\tag{12}
\end{equation}

where:
\$k_e\$, \$k_t\$ - electrical constant, torque constant,
\$p\$ - number of poles

and then phase-to-phase back-emf's can be derived as:
\begin{equation}
e_{ab}= e_a - e_b\tag{13}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_{bc}= e_b - e_c\tag{14}
\end{equation}

and phase-to-phase voltages \$v_{ab}\$, \$v_{bc}\$ are outputs of inverter function, where \$\theta_e\$ is an argument. In BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf there are several examples of tables of inverter output voltages such as:
[image]

Different inverter output voltages gives more or less ripple signals.

Problem is that, in BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf in "Simulation" chapter (page 39 of pdf file) there is wrote that BLDC motor model gives identical speed curve to the traditional DC motor model (which is also described in this pdf file and many other articles), but in my implementation outputs are differents.

Several papers (e.g. http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2011/WCE2011_pp1504-1508.pdf, page 2 of pdf file) shows that in equations (9-12) there are no division by 2.
Other sources show other ways to implement inverter function (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l60p4G7Bdi0).

Depending of which equations or inverter function I use, outputs are very different, so my question is:
Which version of equations and functions give correct outputs?

Edit:
I put here model of DC motor used as reference:
[image]

\begin{equation}
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
i\\
ω_m\\
θ_m
\end{bmatrix}\tag{15}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R}{L} & -\frac{k_e}{L} & 0\\
\frac{k_t}{J} & -\frac{k_f}{J} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{16}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=:
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{L} & 0\\
0 & -\frac{1}{J}\\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{17}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
V_s\\
T_L
\end{bmatrix}\tag{18}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
k_t & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{19}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Y=
\begin{bmatrix}
i\\
ω_m\\
θ_m\\
T_e
\end{bmatrix}\tag{20}
\end{equation}

Here is comparison between simulations with my implementations rotor speed of DC and BLDC motor models:
[image]

for parameters:
\begin{equation}R= 12.5\end{equation}
\begin{equation}L= 0.91\end{equation}
\begin{equation}K_e= 0.01\end{equation}
\begin{equation}J= 0.005\end{equation}
\begin{equation}K_t= 0.01\end{equation}
\begin{equation}K_f= 0.0000000138\end{equation}
\begin{equation}p= 2\end{equation}
\begin{equation}T_L= 0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}Vs= 6\end{equation}
and zero initial conditions.

Comment: Could the factor of 2 come from electrical vs mechanical cycles, in a 4 pole motor?

Comment: I don't know if there is such dependence. Moreover when looking on other papers I see that there are other equations for electrical torque (e. g. shorturl.at/CFRZ5):


\begin{equation}
T_e = \frac{e_a \times i_a + e_b \times i_b + e_c \times i_c}{ω_m}
\end{equation}

Which can be changed into:

\begin{equation}
T_e = k_e[F(θ_e)i_a + F(θ_e-\frac{2π}{3})i_b + F(θ_e-\frac{4π}{3})i_c]
\end{equation}

This suggests that there is relation:

\begin{equation}
k_e=k_t
\end{equation}

but i think that it is incorrect.

Comment: What makes you think ke=kt is incorrect?

Comment: I mean that there is no specific rule that ke is always equal to kt. In many papers these two constants are treated separately (have two different symbols), but I might be wrong.

Comment: Voltage/Speed = Torque/Current. Rearrange to get Voltage * Current = Torque * Speed, or ... Power = Power.

Comment: Ok. After verification with several sources in internet I can agree with you that Ke is equal to Kt but still couldn't find many sources that shows that equation (12) should have relation to number of pole pairs in motor. Moreover many papers shows equations (9-12) without dividing by 2 but take under consideration number of pole pairs in equation (7).