# Is DC motor model give similar output to BLDC motor model with identical parameters?

Tags: dc-motor, simulation, brushless-dc-motor

As in title, I would like to know if DC motor should give similar output (motor speed) to BLDC motor with the same parameters (omitting fact that in outputs of BLDC motor occurs ripples due to electronic commutation)?

Based on following paper:
http://webfiles.portal.chalmers.se/et/MSc/BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf (page 39 of pdf file)
both DC motor model and BLDC motor model should give indentical motor speed, but in my implementation of simulations that is not true, so I would like to know if there is something wrong with my simulation or maybe with this similar outputs information.

Comment: Highly unlikely. Your BLDC is basically an asynchronous three phase motor, possibly with feedback.

Comment: I don't see why brushes would not also ripple.

Comment: @winny Don't you mean synchronous? Not asynchronous?

Comment: I don't have feedback loop in my model. My model is based on BLDC motor and inverter which control voltage on three phases based on electrical angle. But I'm not convinced if my inverter function is correct. In BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf there are several versions of them, but currently I'm using version of inverter function based on this movie:  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l60p4G7Bdi0

Comment: @DKNguyen My bad! They are PM.

Comment: _"DC motor model and BLDC motor model should give indentical motor speed, but in my implementation of simulations that is not true"_ - by how much are they different?

Comment: Here is link to my another post concerning BLDC model:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519423/bldc-motor-simulation
There are showed both DC and BLDC motor models used for simulations and comparison of rotor speed.

Answer (score 2):

A brushed DC motor can be thought of as a brushless DC motor with electromechanical commutation -- and the brushes are half of that commutation mechanism.

So to a first order approximation, with all else being equal, a brushed DC motor and a brushless DC motor will behave the same.

The major difference in construction is that brushed and brushless DC motors tend to be inside out with respect to each other, because it's convenient to put the coils on the rotating part of a brushed motor, and to put them on the non-rotating part of a brushless motor.

The major difference (all else being equal) in use is that a brushes wear out, and are either wimpy or dirty -- really robust brushes are made of graphite composite and leave carbon dust everywhere; precious metal brushes are cleaner but can't stand as much current.

The major difference on the market is that because of all the disadvantages of brushed motors, in consumer electronics it's uncommon to see anything but the cheapest construction in brushed DC motors.  Basically, if you're going to add the cost of good materials, you may as well make it brushless.  A typical metal-can DC brushed motor is a far cry from a good industrial DC brushed motor made with the same magnets and other materials you commonly see in RC toy brushless motors, and their performance is markedly less.  But this is mostly *because of the materials used*, not because of the inherent shortcomings of brushed motors.

So *all else being equal*, a BLDC motor and a DC permanent magnet motor with similar parameters should give similar performance.

Comment: So that mean that both DC motor model and BLDC motor model with the same parameters should give very similar output in simulation and in reality.

Comment: Yes (answer edited).  It may be a good thing if you could share more details about the simulations you're having trouble with.  Or perhaps better, ask a separate question, now that this one is settled.

Comment: Here is link to my another post concerning BLDC model:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519423/bldc-motor-simulation
There are showed both DC and BLDC motor models used for simulations and comparison of rotor speed.

Answer (score 1):

A DC motor and controller combination and s BLDC motor and controller combination with identical combined performance parameters should have identical steady-state speed vs. torque capability. That is really another way of saying that the combined performance parameters are identical. The two systems could have nearly identical dynamic performance as well.

It is likely that the DC motor would need speed feedback to achieve the performance that the BLDC motor could achieve without feedback.

Comment: One thing is that the brushless motor could vary phase advance on the fly with RPM. Brushes obviously can't do that but that's neithere here nor there in the context of OP's question.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, they *could*.  Timing a DC motor is mostly a matter of rotating the brush mount with respect to the magnet mount.  Slot-car racers used to do it statically, it wouldn't be hard to put things on bearing with a lever.  People have had 180 years to put this into practice -- *someone* has.

Comment: @TimWescott I said "on the fly"

Comment: I meant on the fly, although I didn't express that well.  Do you believe that in the last 180 years no clever inventor has put a lever on the brush mounts of a DC motor and tried to make money selling the thing?  Possibly even with some automatic (probably centrifugally activated) gizmo that does the adjusting?

Comment: @TimWescott, I think that electronic control, even with thyratron tubes has been preferred over any kind of brush shifting during the time it has been available. Even prior to that, Ward-Leonard systems, series field resistance and even series armature resistance have been used in various circumstances. There doesn't seem to be much information to indicate that brush shifting has ever been used for very much.

Comment: Sorry for leading things off on a tangent -- no, I very much doubt that it's ever been popular, or even perhaps truly economical.  Just that it is (A) possible, and (B) some time in the 19th century, someone *must* have tried it.